# How to mount a Mojave/HighSierra APFS partition as read only in elementary OS?

Tags: mount

I recently had an issue relating to BootCamp that rendered my Mojave partition unbootable, so I got interested on how to read that APFS partition to retrieve the files using my elementary OS Juno, saved by access through Grub. Fortunately there is a free solution to perform this recovery through apfs-fuse.

Answer (score 1):

Plan

1. There's a 
   free tool to mount APFS drive in linux: apfs-fuse https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse for Linux
2. installation process
   prerequisites (taken from [this](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hacking-macos-break-into-macbook-encrypted-with-filevault-0185177/) walkthrough)
3. compiling
   install missing dependencies by googling the error messages, simply relaunch make

There are many packages that need to be installed to run apfs-fuse. 
use the below command to update APT

`apt-get update`

Then, install the required dependencies with apt-get, as seen below.

`apt-get install zlib1g bzip2 gcc-8-base build-essential cmake clang icu-devtools libicu-dev libghc-bzlib-dev libfuse-dev libattr1-dev`

Clone the Apfs-Fuse Repository:

Next, install Git with apt-get install git.

`apt-get install git`

Then, clone the apfs-fuse repository with git clone github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse.

`git clone https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse`

Change into the newly created apfs-fuse/ directory using the cd command.

`cd apfs-fuse/`

Update the Submodules:

Use git submodule init to initialize the LZFSE compression submodule.

`git submodule init`

Then, use git submodule update to update the LZFSE compression submodule.

`git submodule update`

Wrap Up the Installation:

Create a new directory called build using the mkdir command.

`mkdir build`

Next, change into the directory.

`cd build/`

Then, compile with CMake, a software for managing the build process of software using a compiler-independent method.

`cmake ..`

Last, use make, a utility that will determine automatically which pieces of a program need to be recompiled.

Test Apfs-Fuse:

That's it for downloading and compiling apfs-fuse.

Apfs-fuse's available options can be viewed using the ./apfs-fuse command. Change to the directory where apfs-fuse is located. (/bin or in my case, build).

`./apfs-fuse`

`Options:
-d level      : Enable debug output in the console.
-o options    : Additional mount options.
-v volume-id  : Specify number of volume to be mounted.
-r passphrase : Specify volume passphrase. The driver will ask for it if needed.
-s offset     : Specify offset to the beginning of the container.
-p partition  : Specify partition id containing the container.
-l            : Allow driver to return potentially corrupt data instead of failing, if it can't handle something.`

Create the Mount Destination:

Create a new directory called my_apfs_partition using the mkdir command.

`mkdir /tmp/my_apfs_partition`

Use Apfs-Fuse to mount the Partition

`./apfs-fuse <partition> <mount destination>`

Here's an example of the command I used to mount my MacBook's internal hard drive. When this command is run, apfs-fuse will mount the partition - if encrypted by File Vault, it will prompt for a password.

`./apfs-fuse /dev/sda2 /tmp/my_apfs_partition`

Your APFS partition will then be browsable from that directory!